# Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Suddenly i started having the following error in my terraform automation, it used to work fine and no changes were made.

Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.

on main.tf line 144, in data "aws_ami" "panw":
144: data "aws_ami" "panw" {

I'm using terraform with palo alto firewalls hosted in aws; and running this automation in a codebuild.

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question.

Comment: A `data` block represents a dependency on an external object outside of your current configuration, and so in some sense it's _expected_ to change its result even though you haven't changed your configuration. The relevant question here is whether someone or some automated process has deleted the AMI that this was previously depending on, or changed its metadata in some way that makes it no longer match the search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

**Data Source: aws_ami** is only valid when it returns a single value.

According to [Official documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ami)
*"If more or less than a single match is returned by the search, Terraform will fail."*

Try using **Data Source: aws_ami_ids** instead.

[Data Source:aws_ami_ids](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ami_ids).